# Spring roo and gwt

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I am experimenting with GWT and Roo. I reversed engineered a database with Roo and enabled and scaffolded GWT. During the scaffolding I got couple of these warning:

> The path to type java.util.Set which is used in type ca.cbc.msb.console.Category by the field >'getMedias' needs to be added to the module's gwt.xml file in order to be used in a Proxy.
>   The path to type java.util.Set which is used in type ca.cbc.msb.console.Category by the field >'getSponsors' needs to be added to the module's gwt.xml file in order to be used in a Proxy.

Then I run the app and got the following error trying to browse it

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'ca.cbc.msb.console.client.scaffold.ioc.DesktopInjector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at ca.cbc.msb.console.client.scaffold.ioc.DesktopInjectorWrapper.getInjector(DesktopInjectorWrapper.java:8)
at ca.cbc.msb.console.client.scaffold.Scaffold.onModuleLoad(Scaffold.java:17)
... 9 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:595)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
... 12 more
```

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Roo 1.2.0.M1
By default GWT only looks in ~.client and ~.shared packages. You can try to edit your .gwt.xml to include your packages with the source tag, but I didn't have any luck doing that. I had to start my project over and do 
`database reverse engineer --package ~.client.domain` although I probably should have used ~.shared.domain.

then

```
web gwt setup              
web gwt all --proxyPackage ~.client.proxy --requestPackage ~.client.request
```

I actually had to run that one a couple times. Roo doesn't seem to be creating things in the proper order and errors halfway through